# Alternative to Profiler for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

After some hangs on our public web application, it was recommended by a friend that I use Profiler in order to view db activity from each user (including sprocs and duration). Is there a more widely used database server profiler that I could use in order to better pinpoint issues like this?

Comment: But you can not run trace on Production server , coz it takes a lots of server resource which will in turn causes the over all performance problem in database

Comment: I wouldn't say you can't run it on a production server, but you should be careful about running it.  If the server is normally very heavily loaded then keep the duration of runs short.  If the server usually has spare capacity then there will probably not be any issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never had the need to use anything other than SQL Server Profiler.  It's included specifically for purposes such as you mention.  You can see everything you need to see with Profiler.  Have you run a trace against your server yet?  There are quite a few options that you'll need to configure for your trace in order to narrow down the problem.  It won't necessarily happen on the first trace, either.  It's likely you'll have to do some tweaking of your trace config and rerun a few times in order to see the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

[IdealSqlProfiler](http://idealprogrammer.com/net-languages/c/idealsqltracer-simple-free-open-source-alternative-sql-profiler/) is a free open source alternative to Sql Profiler. IdealSqlProfiler can be used to quickly grab all of the sql that is generated behind a particular individual web page or desktop application. You can find an 11-minute video tutorial on how to use it at [IdealSqlTracer Overview](https://youtu.be/oek38x27tzc)